# How to invisibly identify user account type of user at login?

Tags: authentication, passwords, user-input, user-accounts

I have started building a web app that has different user types - including Admins and Customers, and I want each account type to have its own users db table (sessions system etc), but with the same log in page.

The Admins don't sign up - they are issued an account, whereas the Customer sign up on a page dedicated to creating their account, so at this time and in the future, every user account type will have its own sign up page.

Yet all user account types ie Admins and Customers, should be able to sign in from the same page - without any differences - in the log in form ie no drop down to select user account type being logged into.

My goals are to have:

1. all user account types (3+) log into web app via same form,
2. no need for any visible user account type identifier eg in the formatting of username,
3. as secure as possible 'invisible' user account type identifier.

One solution I've thought of is: hashing the passwords differently per user account type, but with some constant in the hash that can be read on sign in to identify the user account type, that then points the log in process to the right db for that user, but that would require some kind of constant in the hashed output... and I'm stuck. Am I on the right track?

Does anyone know of a script/how-to/or article that covers such a process somewhere?
This must be used in a lot of current web apps.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to have different tables for different account types? You can have a single table with a flag to say what kind of account it is.

Answer (score 0):

Where we've had to implement multiple account types (in big systems I should stress) we always settle on a general (Users) table to supplement the additional tables (Administrators, WebUsers, Suppliers etc)

The Users table would link to either an Administrator, WebUser etc and any 'generic' functionality (i.e. login, logs, recordlocks) would link back to the generic Users table.

Then from a Users record you can deduce what type of account it is and decide what they can/cannot do.

I should stress though that this is only because the structure of these tables is so different that they cannot all be stored in the same table. If there's only 1 column different, for instance, you don't need to do all this.